# Undefined ruby object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

I'm trying to do something ONLY if a variable DOES exist (the variable's name is @filter), the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get the code to work. I keep getting

```
undefined method `male_filter' for nil:NilClass
```

even when the first if should do the trick.
Here's the actual code of the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof <%=@filter%>!='undefined'){
        if(typeof <%=@filter.male_filter%>!='undefined'){
            if(<%=@filter.male_filter%>=='18'){
                $('#18M').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(<%=@filter.male_filter%>=='21'){
                $('#21M').addClass('active');
            }
            else if(<%=@filter.male_filter%>=='24'){
                $('#24M').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a boolean in the controller called filterExists, and did the following:

```
    var filterExists=<%=@filterExists%>;
    if(filterExists==true){...}
```

But I still got the same error:

```
undefined method `male_filter' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: View your page source that is generated! I do not think your serverside code is working like you think it is. Looking at the serverside code is not going to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is all of the ERB is interpreted on the server and then the JavaScript is served to the client where it is run, you are trying to mix server-side and client-side logic.

As long as you understand the ERB is interpreted first, then you can structure your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <% if @filter.present? %>
    <% if @filter.male_filter == '18' %>
      $('#18M').addClass('active');
    <% end %>
    <% if @filter.male_filter == '21' %>
      $('#21M').addClass('active');
    <% end %>
    <% if @filter.male_filter == '24' %>
      $('#24M').addClass('active');
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
});
```

Or more concisely:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <% if @filter %>
    $('#<%= @filter.male_filter %>M').addClass('active');
  <% end %>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a js.erb. You can use regular Ruby in those as well:

```
<% if @filter.present? %>
  <% if @filter.male_filter == "18" %>
    $('#18').addClass('active');
  <% end>
<% end %>
```

Etc.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention, this is a view -> html.erb.